# How to set angular mat-button properties based on an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, async-pipe

I have the following code:

```html
<button mat-button [disabled]="offline() | async"
    [textContent]="scanning() ? 'Stop' : 'Start'"
    (click)="scanning() ? onScanStop() : onScanStart()">
</button>
```

Both `offline()` and `scanning()` return `Observable<boolean>`.
I'm not sure how to use `async` pipe in the case of `scanning()`, it appears to be ok for `offline()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer:**

So after some trials i think you cant prevent adding some code in your back .ts component file.
We will use a variable called `_scanning` in your template:

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="offline() | async"
    [textContent]="_scanning ? 'Stop' : 'Start'"
    (click)="_scanning ? onScanStop() : onScanStart()">
</button>
```

and in your .ts file:

```
  _scanning: boolean = null;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.scanning().subscribe(res => this._scanning = res);
  }
```

**Old answer:**

Try this one:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="scanning | async as _scanning">
    <button mat-button [disabled]="offline() | async "
        [textContent]="_scanning ? 'Stop' : 'Start'"
        (click)="_scanning ? onScanStop() : onScanStart()">
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

store the result of `scanning` observable inside `_scanning` variable when ready and use `_scanning` variable like any other vars

Comment: Use ‘scanning()’ instead of ‘scanning’

Comment: In this case it hides the button.

Comment: @hdoradu I made corrections to the answer. should work for you now.

Comment: Yes, this is kind of what I ended up doing. It does not anyway make sense to subscribe to the observable on (click), so I have a variable populated from the observable callback, and I check that variable. Regarding the [textContent], this one works fine with the async pipe: `(scanning() | async) ? "Stop" :"Start".

Comment: One last thing.. why did you set the button text also between the `<button>` and`</button>` tags? it's already set through `[textContent]` property. Was that intentional?

Comment: Because i tested it without material library. should be removed, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you move your logic outside of the (click) event directly in the component.

Instead call another function; let's call it startScan(). StartScan() will check if scanning() returns true or false and then trigger onScanStop() or onScanStart().

This would definitely work.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be one solution. Thanks you.